# Negation of a sentence written by Oscar Wilde

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If I am asked to negate a sentence such as:

> We are all in the gutter, but some of us are looking at the stars.

would it be "Either there exists someone who is not in the gutter or all of us are not looking at the stars?" I broke it down into $(A$ and $B)$ and then $\sim(A$ and $B)\cong  A $ or $\sim B$ by De Morgan's law. Is this the right way?

Comment: That looks right, except that either usually implies exclusive or, instead of or. I would drop either.

Comment: Alternatively.  He is is claiming we are all in the gutter but ... something... we can negate that with If we are all in the gutter than none of us are looking at the stars and .... we don't have to do any more as if we aren't all in the gutter it is negate.  So $\lnot (a \land b)=a\to \lnot b$ which we knew by truth tables or axioms but... this seems a practical application.

Comment: .....or  ..... If any of us are looking at the stars then we are not all in the gutter..... (this is perversely more fun than it ought to be.)

Comment: @RobArthan I think the first "none of us is" should be "not all of us are".